# How do I count the number of token strings in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of sentences and I would like to count the number of words in each sentence.

So far, I came up with this code, but how can I print the total number of tokens in the whole list?

```py
a = ['je mange.',' je suis là au bain, gyu est là']
b = [elt.split() for elt in a]

print(len(b))

#2
print(b)

#[['je', 'mange.'], ['je', 'suis', 'là', 'au', 'bain,gyu', 'est', 'là']]
```

The total tokens in this example should be `10`.

Comment: `b = [elt.split() for elt in a]` The split function returns a list, so `b` ends up containing two lists.  It sounds like you want to promote the list sub-elements up into the main list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the count, I'd suggest using `len` and `sum`:

```
>>> a = ['je mange.',' je suis là au bain, gyu est là']
>>> sum(map(len, (s.split() for s in a)))
10
```

Answer (score 1):

With your approach, you end with a list of lists - but you're interested in a list of *words*, try this instead:

```
b = [token for elt in a for token in elt.split()]
```

As you can see, now we're counting each word in the input:

```
b
=> ['je', 'mange.', 'je', 'suis', 'l\xc3\xa0', 'au', 'bain,', 'gyu', 'est', 'l\xc3\xa0']
len(b)
=> 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count all of the elements in `b` with this slightly odd piece of code:

```
len(sum(b, []))
```

`sum(b, [])` actually flattens the list of lists into a single list, so `len` of that gives you the overall length.

result: `10`

Although, the simplest approach would be to make a slight modification to your original code.

Where you have:

```
a = ['je mange.',' je suis là au bain, gyu est là']
b = [elt.split() for elt in a]
```

You can simply wrap the `elt.split()` with `len()` to give you:

```
b = [len(elt.split()) for elt in a]
```

So instead of a list of sublists, you have a list of the lengths of the sublists, then `sum(b)` or just `b = sum([len(elt.split()) for elt in a])` will give you your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `list` of splits named `b` is a nested list. Calling `len(b)` will just give you the same value as `len(a)`. Instead, you have to un-nest the list *or* simply add up the `len()` values of the contents:

```py
>>> a = ['je mange.',' je suis là au bain, gyu est là']
>>> b = [elt.split() for elt in a]

>>> token_sizes = [len(token) for token in b]
>>> print(token_sizes)
[2, 8]

>>> total_tokens = sum(token_sizes)
>>> print(total_tokens)
10
```